# Replace line in text containing special characters (mathematical equation) linux text

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I want to replace a line, that represents a part of mathematical equation:

```
f(x,z,time,temp)=-(2.0)/(exp(128*((x-2.5*time)*(x-2.5*time)+(z-0.2)*(z-0.2))))+(
```

with a new one similar to the above. Both new and old lines are saved in bash variables.

Main problem is that mathematical equation is full with special characters that do not allow proper search and replace in bash mode, even when I used as delimiter special character that is not used in equation.

I used

```
sed -n "s|$OLD|$NEW|g" restart.k
```

and

```
sed -i "s|$OLD|$NEW|g" restart.k
```

but all times I get wrong results.
Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `I get wrong results` What results do you get? How are they wrong? Why did you use `-n` switch? How are they saved in bash variables? What are the content of these variables? What are they're values? How are they initialized? You do understand that `sed` parses a regex and regex has special rules how it interprets the meaning of certain characters? Are you aware of these rules? Please create an [MCVE]

Comment: You need to escape special `sed` chars, such as `&`, `\\`, etc.

Comment: That is the goal, that why i used different delimiter, which is not in mathematical equation. Finally results are the same: I cannot search and replace the equation.

Comment: Escape or include the special characters int a `[...]` list so that they lose their special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only `*` in your pattern here that is special for `sed`, so escape it and do replacement as usual:

```
sed "s:$(sed 's:[*]:\\&:g' <<<"$old"):$new:" infile
```

if there are more special characters in your real sample, then you will need to add them inside bracket `[]`; there are some exceptions like:

- if `^` character: it can be place anywhere in `[]` but not first character, because `^` character at first negates the characters within its bracket expression.
- if `]` character: it should be the first character, because this character is also used to end the bracket expression.
- if `-` character: it should be the first or last character, because this character is also can be used for defining the range of characters too.